# how to get around VBScript runtime error for type mismatch; code: 800a000D

Tags: command-line, microsoft-office, script, microsoft-office-2010, vbscript

I might not be doing this right, but I am trying to modify a VBScript for finding Windows Product key to support finding a Product Key for Microsoft Office Pro. Here is the code, but I would like the "unknown" folder name to have the same effect as a wildcard. I know an actual wildcard is not possible in VBScript, but what can I do to return the registry value for "DigitalProductID" in the script without specifying the "unknown" folder? Or do I change the code somewhere else?

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Registration\unknown\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Comment: You open up `regedit` and lookup that "unkown" part manually, substitute it and run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Next simple script enumerates subkeys of a given registry key:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Goto 0

Dim strLog, strComputer, objRegistry, strKeyPath, key, arrsubKeys

strLog = ""
strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
      & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Registration\"
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\"    '''' key path for demonstration 

strLog = strLog & vbNewLine & "subkeys of HKLM\" & strKeyPath

objRegistry.EnumKey HKLM, strKeyPath, arrsubKeys

If VarType( arrsubKeys) = 8204 Then
    For Each key In arrsubKeys
        strLog = strLog & vbNewLine & key
    Next
End If

Wscript.Echo strLog
Wscript.Quit

' useful constants '
' Registry: Braches and Corresponding Hexadecimal Values '
Const HKCR = &H80000000 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Const HKCU = &H80000001 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Const HKU  = &H80000003 'HKEY_USERS
Const HKCC = &H80000005 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
Const HKDD = &H80000006 'HKEY_DYN_DATA
```